# Cross compilation using Renesas G1E toolchain. Getting linker error though library files are already there in lib directory

Tags: c, embedded, cross-compiling, libconfig, libmosquitto

I am trying cross compile C code (outside yocto) using toolchain (/home/amruta/Downloads/poky-glibc-x86_64-core-image-weston-sdk-cortexa7hf-neon-toolchain-2.4.2.sh) for renesas G1E module. Procedure followed to cross compile :

1. Installed given toolchain
2. Set environment :

```
amruta@amruta-OptiPlex-3060:~$ . /opt/poky/2.4.2/environment-setup-cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi
```

3. Compiling in same terminal :

```
amruta@amruta-OptiPlex-3060:~/amruta/amruta_projects/G1E/EnergyMeterApp1/src$ $CC *.c -o Energymeter -L /opt/poky/2.4.2/sysroots/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/libmosquitto -I /opt/poky/2.4.2/sysroots/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/
```

Source files used for cross compilation :

```
amruta@amruta-OptiPlex-3060:~/amruta/amruta_projects/G1E/EnergyMeterApp1/src$ ls
client_shared_lib.c  EnergyMeterApp1.h  GenericFunctions.c  modbus                 ProcessHandler.c
client_shared_lib.h  FileLogger.c       GenericFunctions.h  mosq_pub_sub_client.c  ProcessHandler.h
FileLogger.h       libconfig.h         mosq_pub_sub_client.h  ReadAllConfigs.c
EnergyMeterApp1.c    GenericDefns.h     Makefile            mosquitto.h            ReadAllConfigs.h
```

Library files already present in  lib dir

```
amruta@amruta-OptiPlex-3060:~$ ls /opt/poky/2.4.2/sysroots/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib | grep libmos
libmosquitto.so.1
amruta@amruta-OptiPlex-3060:~$ ls /opt/poky/2.4.2/sysroots/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib | grep libconf
libconfig.so.9
libconfig++.so.9
libconfig.so.9.2.0
libconfig++.so.9.2.0
amruta@amruta-OptiPlex-3060:~$
```

Header files present in include dir

```
amruta@amruta-OptiPlex-3060:~$ ls /opt/poky/2.4.2/sysroots/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/ | grep mos
mosquitto.h

amruta@amruta-OptiPlex-3060:~$ ls /opt/poky/2.4.2/sysroots/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/ | grep libconfig
libconfig.h
```

Build output (partial):

```
amruta@amruta-OptiPlex-3060:~/amruta/amruta_projects/G1E/EnergyMeterApp1/src$ $CC *.c -o Energymeter -L /opt/poky/2.4.2/sysroots/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/libmosquitto -I /opt/poky/2.4.2/sysroots/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/ 

/tmp/ccBMhPYg.o: In function client_id_generate': 
client_shared_lib.c:(.text+0x64): undefined reference to mosquitto_lib_cleanup' 
client_shared_lib.c:(.text+0x144): undefined reference to `mosquitto_lib_cleanup' 

/tmp/ccRMPfVp.o: In function ReadEnergyMeterConfigs': 
ReadAllConfigs.c:(.text+0x374): undefined reference to config_init' 
ReadAllConfigs.c:(.text+0x384): undefined reference to config_read_file' 
ReadAllConfigs.c:(.text+0x3c8): undefined reference to config_destroy'
```

Please suggest for successful cross compilation.

Comment: amruta@amruta-OptiPlex-3060:~/amruta/amruta_projects/G1E/EnergyMeterApp1/src$ $CC *.c -o Energymeter -L /opt/poky/2.4.2/sysroots/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/libmosquitto -I /opt/poky/2.4.2/sysroots/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/
/tmp/ccBMhPYg.o: In function `client_id_generate':
client_shared_lib.c:(.text+0x64): undefined reference to `mosquitto_lib_cleanup'
client_shared_lib.c:(.text+0x144): undefined reference to `mosquitto_lib_cleanup'

Comment: /tmp/ccRMPfVp.o: In function `ReadEnergyMeterConfigs':
ReadAllConfigs.c:(.text+0x374): undefined reference to `config_init'
ReadAllConfigs.c:(.text+0x384): undefined reference to `config_read_file'
ReadAllConfigs.c:(.text+0x3c8): undefined reference to `config_destroy'
Those are partial errors. Couldn't post all error messages

Comment: Do not use comments for information that should be in your question; they are limited length, limited formatting capability and are for neither answers nor questions.  Edit the question to fix or improve your question.  I have added the logs to your question and fixed other Markdown formatting issues.

Answer (score 1):

Specifying a library directory (`-L <dir>`) will not cause any libraries therein to be linked.  The `-L` switch only tells the linker where to look for libraries specified by `-l <lib>` switches, of which you have none.

You need to add `-l mosquitto` to link libmosquitto.so for example. Similarly `-l config` for libconfig.so.

In general for any library libXXX.so or libXXX.a you link it with `-l XXX`.  Where the libraries are versioned as in this case, the latest version will be linked.  To link a specific version, you don't use `-l <lib>` but simply specify the path to the specific .so file as an input without a '`-`' switch.